# binary divison with remainder

Tags: arithmetic, binary, number-systems, binary-operations

I wanted to calculate this (binary):

10101.101/1.1.

the result is:

1110.01101010101010101010101010...

I succeed in calculating the integer part, but I didn't understand how I find the numbers that are after the decimal point (not all of them of course, just to find the first 4 numbers for example).

I tried to google it, but I only saw simple examples of dividing binary numbers, without numbers like this.

how do I caclulate this correctly?

Comment: Compute $101011.01/11$. The algorithm is the same as in the decimal case.

Comment: tnx, I know understand my problem. I tried to calculate with different algorithm that seems to work only at some simple cases.